# Grails ajax-uploader

Tags: ajax, grails, file-upload

Can anyone tell me if the Grails file-uploader plugin supports ajax-uploading of images?

Because I'm trying to develop an AJAX image upload and download feature, can I do it using file-uploader plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I use the `JQuery Uploadify` plugin dude , it  use for ajax upload and need flash plugin

note : if you want to use ajax upload you have to use the Flash plugin, because ajax upload without postback you page is impossible dude  , and make just by Flash

i search many about this , and the best thing that i found for ajax upload , is JQuery Uploadify plugin that is used in Gmail too

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the [file uploader](http://grails.org/plugin/file-uploader) grails plugin. It does not support ajax uploading.

There is another plugin called [ajax uploader](http://grails.org/plugin/ajax-uploader) and I've tested it as well. This uses the javascript for file uploading with progress image, however the plugin is not really easy to use. You basically need to implement how you handle the file after it uploads it.